# regex to extract a portion of a string

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression to search for a portion of a string and then extract a subsequent parameter...

Source strings here:

```
5288470F7E7155F1A19D7236F837D3CC:120//
5288470F7E7155F1A19D7236F837D3DD:20//
5288470F7E7155F1A19D72DAFF:9302//
```

The source string could be any length and always follow the same pattern:
ID:result//

I need to be able to search the string for the longer ID and then extract the subsequent number between the : and the // pattern.
So give this as a search string `"5288470F7E7155F1A19D7236F837D3DD"` - I need to get the result "20"

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+//

Comment: `:([0-9]+)` https://regex101.com/r/rK3jM2/1

Comment: What language? In PHP something like `'~//' . preg_quote($target) . ':(\d+)~'`

Answer (score 0):

Using grep you can do it in following way:

```
grep -Po "(?<=$target_string:)\d+(?=\/\/)"
```

This will print only the number that you require. The regex used is Perl Compatible.